# Jquery - Internet Explorer submitting form twice

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, submit, double-submit-problem

I have the following code which I use to submit forms with links (instead of buttons).  This is so that we can do some CSS hover stuff with them.

```
$('a.css_submit').click(submit_form);
$('a.inactive_submit').click(submit_form);

function submit_form(event) {
  if ($(this).parents('form:first').length > 0 && !$(this).hasClass('inactive_submit'))   {
        $(this).toggleClass("css_submit inactive_submit");
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

The issue is that Internet Explorer occasionally submits the form twice.  I haven't been able to replicate the problem myself, but I can verify it in my production server logs.  This problem persists in IE6 - IE9.  All other browsers work fine.  I've seen some posts that say to return false from the link, but I'm doing that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe users are clicking submit twice really fast. Try disabling the link after the first click.

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you use event.preventDefault() as the first line of submit_form? (instead of return false;)

Comment: +1 @ilia this is often the case. The general population is used to double-clicking Windows icons, so they tend to double-click _everything_. I wrote an online payment system some years ago and we disabled the submit button onclick (in addition to server-side validation) in order to deter double submissions.

Comment: I probably should add something to disable the link after the first click, but the problem is *only* in IE.  Theoretically, any browser could be clicking twice - but the other browsers aren't producing duplicate submissions.

Comment: I don't find it unlikely that people who double-click everything are also people who use IE.

Comment: Could it be two bindings from loading some file in twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some extra validation to make sure it doesn't get clicked twice:

```
var formSubmitted = false;

function submit_form(event) {
  if(formSubmitted  == true) { alert('Form already submitted.'); return false; } // determine if form is already submitted
  if ($(this).parents('form:first').length > 0 && !$(this).hasClass('inactive_submit'))   {
        $(this).toggleClass("css_submit inactive_submit");
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
    return false;
  } else {
    formSubmitted  = true;
    $('a.css_submit').attr('disabled', true); // disable form submit button
    $('a.css_submit').val('Processing...'); // set form submit button text to say processing
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you `submit` the form yourself you need to also cancel event's default processing.

The jquery way is `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$(this).parents('form:first').submit();
event.preventDefault();
```

Returning `true` / `false` has no effect in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

For IE, you can use following code :

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

we can check if preventDefault exists to avoid error :

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
```

Answer (score 0):

For IE, I found this :

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

First check if event.preventDefault exists to prevent an eventual error :

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
```